# How can I run a test on 20+ sites from a single console?

Tags: bash, expect

I'd like to run a test script on dozens of embedded Linux units; in manufacturing the authentication credentials are all the same.

The tests are about an hour, but I'd like each unit to loop continuously (over the weekend say) and report the current iteration of the test (on a per unit basis).

I'm thinking expect might be the way to go (it would certainly help with ssh login), but the online documentation is ... uh ... a bit too distributed for what seems to be a simple exercise.

I'm stuck at the trying to determine how to `spawn` my embedded tests in parallel.  In BASH I'd use the `&` operator to put the process on the background, but then entering the authentication is a challenge.

Should I use expect or stick with BASH scripting?

---

What I did:

Using an `expect` script I placed an SSH authentication file on the DUT.  THE DUT's have only a RAM file system to play with so this before the rest of the bash script is run. Then, a simple BASH for loop issues an ssh command inside a for loop to run the tests and put the session on a background thread. Comme ca:

```
for i in <IP devices to test> ;
    do
        ssh user@$i "echo - \"IP Address: $i :\" ; test-script" &
    done
```

Voila!

Comment: Your test scripts resides on units and want to ssh into these units and run these scripts?

Comment: @dhchen Yes. The scripts are on the units; and I run them with SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup ssh public-key authentication (example: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/532.cfm) with blank public key password, then you can use ssh to run these scripts without entering any authorization credential, thus you can write bash scripts to execute them without user intervention

Comment: Would love too, but the SSH key changes with each software load; one of the reasons this isn't practical.  Another is that once the script gets written, it will be shared with Manufacturing.  The users of the software/scripts aren't technical, asking them to setup public-key authentication for units that roll off the line for go/nogo testing really borks up the manufacturing process.

Comment: Then maybe you can try to setup a shell by `nc` on these units (`nc -l -p port -v -e /bin/bash` or something like that) and echo scripts to the units (`echo -n "tests.sh\n" | nc unis.ip.addr port`)

Comment: Not a practical answer either (I'd have to log in to setup the nc session, not to mention its not on the embedded system) but +1 for putting nc in my tool box. What a nifty little program.

Comment: You know what? I was able to use `expect` to place an authentication file on the DUT, then use BASH scripts to ssh into the DUTs.  The BASH scripts use the `&` to put the DUT ssh session on a background thread. +1